# How to list Supplementary Tables (table, longtable, landscape)?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, environments, longtable, landscape

I need to list Supplementary Tables separated from main tables.

This is, to replicate exactly the answer from this post, but for tables, considering that I have different table environments (`table`, `longtable`, `landscape`):

[How to list supplementary figures in the list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/how-to-list-supplementary-figures-in-the-list-of-figures)

This is the code employed for figures which is actually working

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure},fileext=lsf,listname={List of 
Supplementary Figures}]{suppfigure}
```

I guess problems arise due to the `longtable` characteristics

[How to create a new environment that contains multi-page longtables with unique caption labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421765/how-to-create-a-new-environment-that-contains-multi-page-longtables-with-unique)

[Issue in using longtable within table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227402/issue-in-using-longtable-within-table-environment)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for making custom Supplementary Table environment

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Table},fileext=lst,listname={List of 
Supplementary Tables}]{supptable}
```

And then you use

```
\begin{supptable}
.................. %<----- Some table environment here
\caption{some caption}
\end{supptable}
```

And to make the list of supplementary tables appear you can `\listofsupptables`.

[image: lssupptable]

**UPDATE:**

For the `longtable`, I had to use `\captionof` just to emulate the float caption so that it gets added to the list and then allow the `longtable` to be written as usual as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Table},fileext=lsst,listname={List of 
Supplementary Short Tables},within=section, placement=htbp!]{supptable}

\def\nlines#1{\expandafter\nlineii\romannumeral\number\number #1 000\relax}
\def\nlineii#1{\if#1m\expandafter\theline\expandafter\nlineii\fi}

\begin{document}

\listofsupptables
\clearpage

\begin{supptable}
\centering
\caption{Short Table}
\begin{tabular}{|cccc|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{supptable}

\def\theline{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\}

\begingroup
\captionof{supptable}{Long Table}
\endgroup
\begin{longtable}{|cccc|c|}
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\nlines{100}
\hline                                                                                                                                 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This is adapted from here, where @David Carlisle's comment was useful: [How to create a new environment that contains multi-page longtables with unique caption labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421765/how-to-create-a-new-environment-that-contains-multi-page-longtables-with-unique)

Comment: Works only on table environment but not on longtable  or landscape

Comment: It might be easier to use \listoftables to list supplimetary tables and \listofsuptables (more or less) to list plain tables.  Check out \listtablename.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You may try it now for the longtable.

Comment: That works! Thank you